# Using cache tags with eloquent relationships in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-4, redis

I am needing to add a redis cache tag to eloquent model relationships for example:

```
 public function children() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('table1', 'table2', 'field1', 'field2')->where('field3', 'value')->orderBy('field1', 'asc')->remember(720);
 }
```

but I currently have no way of clearing this cache without waiting for it to expire. I understand there may be a way of adding a cache name to it which could be cleared with Cache::forget($name) but I want to add the same cache tag to it as lots of other entries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use Redi's tags then eparate relation method from cache method:

```
public function children() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('table1', 'table2', 'field1', 'field2')->where('field3', 'value')->orderBy('field1', 'asc')->remember(720);
}

public function getChildren() {
     return Cache::tags(['tag1', 'teg2])->rememberForever('cacheKey', function() {
        return $this->children()->get();
    })
}
```

Then If you want to clear it use Redis's tag option flush like this i.e.:

```
Cache::tags('tag1')->flush();
```